# Excel VBA : Print Data cells within a range

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to print cells (ranges) which have data. In my Sheet **B:T** is the print area. If in that range Only upto Range B8:T8 (rows)have values remaining are empty. So I need a macro which Print only data cells in **B:T** range

Answer (score 0):

Try and do some digging next time as that is really easy to write and good practice for you. You just need to find last row in range and set a print area to A1:T & lastrow.

```
setPrintArea()
Dim LR As Long
LR = Columns("B:T").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.printArea = "B1:T" & LR
End Sub
```